# Calculating distance from point to points along roads using ArcGIS Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst

i have start poin(living city) and 10 other points and road network, I want calculate distance from my start point (my living city) to each other city along the road network. **In the result i want 10 distances for every point.  **  I dont know which analysis use for it.

I am using ArcGIS 10.4 with all extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, There are many ways to do that using ArcGIS, by network analyst.

First, make New network dataset with your road network only [[Tutorial]](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/exercise-1-creating-a-network-dataset.htm).

Second, you can use one of the following (also, there are other options):

- [Closest Facility](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/exercise-4-finding-the-closest-fire-stations.htm) (good option): by defining your main point as facilities, and your other points as incidents. The result will be something like that:

[image]

- [OD cost matrix](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/exercise-5-calculating-service-area-and-creating-an-od-cost-matrix.htm): by defining your main point as the origin and other points as destinations.

  These links will help you [[Closest Facility](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/closest-facility.htm), [OD cost matrix]](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/od-cost-matrix.htm)